# How to make button using canvas in toplevel() Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a button using `canvas.create_window` in `toplevel()` in Tkinter. Button is used to go back to main window. First "Start" button is displayed but second "Back" button is not. Code below.

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def play_button():
    win.withdraw()
    top = Toplevel()
    top.geometry("300x300")
    button_back = Button(top, text="Back", command=back_button)

    canvas_two = Canvas(top, width = 300, height = 300)    
    canvas_two.pack(fill="both", expand=True)         
    Button_reverse = canvas_two.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=button_back)
    top.resizable(False, False)

def back_button():
    win.deiconify()

win.geometry("300x300")

canvas = Canvas(win, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)      
button_play = Button(win, text="Play", command=play_button)
Play_button = canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=button_play )

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: The code in your question **will** produce errors. Please edit your question again and provide a [mre].

Comment: @jasonharper: I don't think that question is a dup (yet). The `background_two` in the OP's code isn't being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the ordering of creation of `canvas_two` and `button_back`. You need to create the `Canvas` first and then put the `Button` on top of it as shown below.

```
def play_button():
    win.withdraw()
    top = Toplevel()
    top.geometry("300x300")

    canvas_two = Canvas(top, width=300, height=300)
    canvas_two.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    button_back = Button(top, text="Back", command=back_button)
    Button_reverse = canvas_two.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=button_back)
    top.resizable(False, False)
```